# Exportar a PDF - LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, pdf

Hay alguna forma de exportar una tabla  a PDF
Actualmente lo que hago es "Consultar nuevamente la Base" me genera la tabla en mi vista. Y exporto, pero quiero evitar hacer nuevamente la consulta.

Ya que estoy mostrando en un vista una tabla y si el usuario   Necesita exportar A PDF usar ese mismo contenido, sin necesidad de consultar nuevamente la base. ¿Exista alguna forma de reutilizar el contenido?

Estoy con laravel

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slCwrm64IWA

Comment: te recomiendo utilizar laravel-snappy de barryvdh https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy , así, podrás exportar el contenido de tu vista a pdf, debes leer toda la documentación para evitar problemas de instalación y funcionamiento, saludos.